# Receive tcp request with unknown message size

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a tcp listener set up where i have an unknown message size coming in. I am not sure what the best practice is when it comes to handling unknown message sizes. Here is the code:

```
TcpListener _server = new TcpListener(_localAddr, _port);
_server.Start();
while (true)
{
    if (_server.Pending())
    {
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];//Works fine if message under this size
        string data = string.Empty;
        _client = _server.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream stream = _client.GetStream();
        int i;
        while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {
            data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
            data = data.ToUpper();
            //Do stuff with data
        }
}
```

So you will notice i can change the size of the array bytes from 256 to something bigger but i don't know if there is a better way than just setting the size to something i know is big enough. If the message is smaller than 256 it works fine.

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the messages length is not permanent the service who send you the messages should send you in the beginning of every message a few bytes (usually 4 because Int32 is 32 bits that are 4 bytes) that will indicate the message length.
When you receive the message you should first read this 4 bytes, then after you parse them you will know the message length and you can create array of bytes in the appropriate size.

Now you can read to this array the message itself.

Comment: So the client told me the following: Every XML message that Matrix sends to the Interface Server will end with an EOT (0x04) byte. So this is at end of message instead of beginning. Not sure how it being at the end will help me.

Comment: There is another approach except the one above, in this approch you will get a delimiter that will indicates that this is the end of the message, in this case you should iterate byte after byte in the message until you get to the delimiter, you cannot know the end of the message before you will get to it. So you should allocate some memory to begin with to hold the message, but if you notice while iterating over the bytes that the message is bigger than the allocated memory you should increase it.

Comment: Yes this is what i am currently going to do thanks. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way.